# How to detect plurals in English sentences?

Tags: parsers, natural-language-processing

I'm wondering how to detect English plurals in natural language sentences.

Such as:

fish
computer**s**
house**s**
...

Using Earley parsing I'm able to get to the **s** or **no-s**, but I have difficulties in understanding how to figure out whether the ending **s** is because the word is in plural form. Or whether with **no-s** the word is in plural form.

Is this kind of thing doable without some database of words and their plurals? I could leverage such database though, if such exists.

Comment: You will need a database, and such databases (called dictionaries) exist.

Comment: If `bus` is not the plural of `bu` and the plural of `woman` is not `womans`, this approach is doomed. I don't know what your big end goal is, but the pattern of your questions is consistent: you lack basic expertise. I recommend you consult experts (CS, lingustics, NLP) if this is about work, or start at the bottom if it's pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Morphological parsing requires a lexicon (stems and their part of speech) , morphotactics (ordering of morpheme classes), and orthographic rules (e.g. fox + PL = foxes rather than foxs).

The preferred approach is to use a composition of finite state transducers to map a surface level representation (e.g., foxes) into its lexical representation (e.g., fox +N +Pl).

For a robust method, you are better off using an existing system like Foma, lttoolbox, or SFST than writing your own system since these systems come with rich morphological data sets.